# Undirected graph connection

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I have an assignment that I'm trying to do using Java, any help or guidance would be much appreciate it, below is the question

> I have been given an integer N and two arrays A and B, I should return true if there exists a path from vertex 1 to N going through all vertices, one by one , in increasing order or false otherwise.

Given  N=4 , A=[1,2,4,4,3] and B[2,3,1,3,1] below function should return true, because there is a path (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4) using edges (1,2) (2,3) and (4,3)

```
public boolean dfs(int N, int[] A, int[] B){}
```

Comment: What do A and B represent? Can you post B?

Comment: @krezno A and B are arrays that describes an edge between vertex A[K] and and vertex B[K]

Comment: Did you learn about the dfs algorithm? Seems its the name of your function template

Comment: any solution would be find @krezon thanks

Comment: I think it would be easier if you build an adjacency matrix or an adjacency list. For the beginning, I would recommend matrix. And then you can find how to implement DFS algorithm using an adjacency matrix. If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: @geobreze , thanks I'll  try later,  building an arraylist adjacency and then implement it using DFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Matt suggests, you do not need to look at all edges using a search; instead, it is enough to look for each of the (known) required edges; and you can fail as soon as you find that a required edge is missing. Thus,

```
public static boolean incrementalConnected(int N, int A[], int B[]) {
    Set<String> edges = new HashSet<>(N); // quick lookup
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int lo = Math.min(A[i], B[i]);
        int hi = Math.max(A[i], B[i]);
        edges.add("" + lo + "-" + hi);    // undirected
    }

    for (int i=1; i<N; i++) {
        if (! edges.contains("" + i + "-" + (i+1))) {
            return false; // missing a required edge
        }
    }
    return true; // all required edges present
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know exactly the N-1 edges you need -- 1-2 or 2-1, 2-3 or 3-2, etc. -- and so there is no need to do a search of the graph.

You should just make an array of N-1 Booleans representing these edges.  Check all the edges you have, and whenever you see one that you need, set it's Boolean to true.

Finally, check to see if all your Booleans are true.